# Problem initializing react components for the tree project

Tags: reactjs, initialization

I encounter an unexpected problem on react when composing my file structure for my new website project.

I just created my tree structure and I got the wrong file name, I deleted my 'header' folder with my 'Header.jsx' and 'header.css'.

I recreated two home and header files and I get this error :

Compiled with problems : X

```
ERROR in ./src/App.jsx 7:0-48
Module not found: Error: Cannot find file: 'Header.jsx' does not match the corresponding name on disk: '.\src\components\header\Header'.
```

Here is my App.js file :

```
import React from 'react'
import './index.css'

// import Nav from './components/nav/Nav'
import Header from './components/header/Header'
import Home from './components/home/Home'
import About from './components/about/About'
import Services from './components/services/Services'
import Prices from './components/prices/Prices'
import Contact from './components/contact/Contact'
import Footer from './components/footer/Footer'

const App = () => {
  return (
    <> 
        {/* <Nav /> */}
        <Header />
        <Home />
        <About />
        <Services />
        <Prices />
        <Services />
        <Contact />
        <Footer />
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

I can't seem to fix the error, even closing vscode and relaunching npm gives me the same error every time I delete a folder or change the name of a component in my framework.

How to solve this problem ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: give us more details. header component location and how are you eporting that component.

Comment: Thanks for your return, i create / delete x3 times the folder and the problem disappeared, for me it was like an unknown bug !